# Python vlc check if song is playing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, vlc

I have this Python script:

```
import mysql.connector
import os
import time
import vlc
from subprocess import Popen
from mysql.connector import Error

def program():
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='broadcast',
                                         user='****',
                                         password='****')
    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)
        
    sql_select_Query = "select * from broadcast WHERE datumtijd BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE AND now()"
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_select_Query)
    # get all records
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Total number of rows in table: ", cursor.rowcount)
    print("\n")

    #print("\nPrinting each row")
    for row in records:
        print("\nPrinting each row")
        print("id = ", row[0], )
        print("date_time  = ", row[1])
        print("audiofile  = ", row[2], "\n")
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer('/home/pi/Music/' + row[2])
        player.play()
        
        
runprogram = True
while runprogram:
    program()
    time.sleep(10)
```

This code check if there is a record in a mysql database and if the time matches it will play that song.
No problems so far, but the script is sitting in a while loop of 10 seconds.
After 10 seconds the same song is played again, so there are 2 songs playing at that moment.
And after another 10 seconds it starts for the 3rd time, etc. ect.

Is there any possibility to change my code, so it doens't start another song if there is a song playing.
If yes, what do I need to add/change to make this work.

Gr. Edwin

Comment: You can create some lock file, typically in /var/run and check if it exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply hold the `player` open while it's still playing with a `while` loop.

e.g.

```
import time
import vlc

input_files = ['punish.mp3', 'trial.wav', 'punish2.mp3']

def program():
    for row in input_files:
        print("Playing: ", row)
        player = vlc.MediaPlayer('../'+row)
        player.play()
        time.sleep(1) # allow player to start
        while player.is_playing():
            time.sleep(1)        
        
runprogram = True
while runprogram:
    program()
    print("Finished: Looping for more audio")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Output:

```
python 20220227.py
Playing:  punish.mp3
Playing:  trial.wav
Playing:  punish2.mp3
Finished: Looping for more audio
Playing:  punish.mp3
Playing:  trial.wav
Playing:  punish2.mp3
Finished: Looping for more audio
Playing:  punish.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found this: https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.MediaPlayer-class.html#is_playing

Basically, there is a method for checking if the player is already playing (`player.is_playing()`).
So you just have to preserve the reference to the vlc.MediaPlayer somewhere in the code and then check if it is playing before starting the player again.

Comment: I've found this also, but can't seem to find any example how to implement this into my code.

I've tried to add this into my while loop but this doesn't work (off course):
'code'
while runprogram:
    program()
    player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
    if player.is_playing():
        print("OK, player is already playing a song")
    else:
        time.sleep(10)