# python-vlc running out of memory after playing multiple songs

Tags: python, memory-management, raspberry-pi, python-vlc

I am writing a python program, running on a raspberry pi (PI 3 A+), that plays a song every 10 minutes.  I am using [python-vlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings/) to play the song through the pi's headphone jack.

PlaySong() is a function that gets called (successfully) every 10 minutes.

```
import vlc

def PlaySong():
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:///home/pi/music.mp3")
    p.play()
```

This works as expected the first 6 times.  After 6 times, it doesn't play anymore, and instead throws this error:

```
mmap() failed: cannot allocate memory
```

This happens even when I change it from every 10 minutes to every 2 minutes, so it doesn't have to do with the amount of time.

Task Manager shows that there is still plenty of memory available on the pi itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably need to close the opened file once it finishes playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is running out of memory because the media player was not released.  The solution is to add in `p.release()` after playing the song.  This will stop the song immediately, so we will want to add in `time.sleep()` before `p.release()`.

The final code would look something like this:

```
import time
import vlc
def PlaySong():
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:///home/pi/music.mp3")
    p.play()
    time.sleep(5) #play for 5 seconds
    p.release()
```

If you want the mp3 to play for the entire duration of the song, you can [loop until it's done playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71279020/python-vlc-check-if-song-is-playing), like this:

```
import time
import vlc
def PlaySong():
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer("file:///home/pi/music.mp3")
    p.play()
    time.sleep(1) #this is necessary because is_playing() returns false if called right away
    while p.is_playing():
        time.sleep(1)
    p.release()
```